# Issue with display of multiple lines of text columns in document library columns

Tags: content-type, document-set, quick-parts

I have a document library with a Document Set content type associated.
This content type is composed of several site columns and has a Word document associated as a default template.

I have added quick parts to this Word document for users to fill it, and then get the columns' metadata filled automatically in SharePoint from this document.

It all works fine, excepted when I define shared columns of type "multiple lines of text" in the document set settings; they don't display in my Document Library columns and are even not saved in the document properties at all.
All other types of columns (single line of text, choice...) are saved in document properties and display well in the Document Library columns, but not this type of column.

If I remove the "shared columns" option for them, then it works fine (I need to use shared columns since I want other documents added to this Document Library to use the same metadata).

Any clue on this?

Thanks for your support,